# Trouble installing OpenVPN

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, openvpn

I tried following their guide for installing [OpenVPN via repository](https://openvpn.net/download-open-vpn/) for Ubuntu 18 but ran into a few issues. After entering the first command:

```
apt update && apt -y install ca-certificates wget net-tools
```

I'm hit with the following errors.

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I then tried adding "sudo" in front of the original command it seems to have fixed one of the problems but still receive errors at the end.

```
Hit:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Get:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [586 kB]
Get:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [740 kB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,007 kB]
Get:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [980 kB]
Fetched 3,564 kB in 6s (601 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
24 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I'm not sure what to do from here. Any advice?

Comment: You have two commands munged together with a "&&". Separate them and try each separately. Then you will see the problem right away. Optional: Also get rid of the "-y": It eliminates an important protection.

Comment: You forgot `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Running the commands separately as shown below should solve the problem as the commands are munged together with "&&"

```
sudo apt update
```

Then

```
sudo apt -y install ca-certificates wget net-tools
```

Thanks to [user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733) for his comment.